# ClaimsPrincipal.Current Visual Studio 2017 different behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I am running a VS2012 MVC 5 project on 2017 . All seems to work fine except that 
`ClaimsPrincipal.Current` does not return the same thing!!

The exact same code works perfectly on VS2012 , Development and Production server.
Although when running the project from VS2017 `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` behaves differently.

Doing some research i found this article
http://davidpine.net/blog/principal-architecture-changes/

Stating that in .NET Core `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` should behave differently .

Thing is that in my case i am running the exact same .NET version in both IDE's (4.0.30319.42000)  and verified that  with `Environment.Version`.

Also hitting F12 on `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` navigates to the exact same mscorlib.dll file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was causing this !

```
WebMatrix.Data.dll
WebMatrix.WebData.dll
```

When these files are present in the bin folder, they cause this behavior .
Additionally they overwrite RazorVersion and cause the Development server to throw not matching assembly reference exceptions.

In my project i had a reference to **WebMatrix.WebData Version 2.0.0.0**

Visual Studio 2012 was ignoring that reference for some reason and it wasn't publishing WebMatrix.dll to the bin folder so everything was working fine.

Visual Studio 2017 was publishing those dlls into the bin folder and that caused this conflict which probably was overriding the built in  **Simple Membership Provider** implementation.

Removing the reference to **WebMatrix** fixed the issue.